# Query with and without $elemMatch is giving me the same results

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

Query with and without **elemMatch** is giving me the same results:

```
db.inventory.find({dim_cm: { $elemMatch :{$gt:1}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04608"), "item" : "journal", "qty" : 25, "tags" : [ "blank", "red" ], "dim_cm" : [ 14, 21 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04609"), "item" : "notebook", "qty" : 50, "tags" : [ "red", "blank" ], "dim_cm" : [ 14, 21 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460a"), "item" : "paper", "qty" : 100, "tags" : [ "red", "blank", "plain" ], "dim_cm" : [ 14, 21 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460b"), "item" : "planner", "qty" : 75, "tags" : [ "blank", "red" ], "dim_cm" : [ 22.85, 30 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460c"), "item" : "postcard", "qty" : 45, "tags" : [ "blue" ], "dim_cm" : [ 10, 15.25 ] }
> 
> 
> db.inventory.find({dim_cm: { $gt:1 }})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04608"), "item" : "journal", "qty" : 25, "tags" : [ "blank", "red" ], "dim_cm" : [ 14, 21 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04609"), "item" : "notebook", "qty" : 50, "tags" : [ "red", "blank" ], "dim_cm" : [ 14, 21 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460a"), "item" : "paper", "qty" : 100, "tags" : [ "red", "blank", "plain" ], "dim_cm" : [ 14, 21 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460b"), "item" : "planner", "qty" : 75, "tags" : [ "blank", "red" ], "dim_cm" : [ 22.85, 30 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460c"), "item" : "postcard", "qty" : 45, "tags" : [ "blue" ], "dim_cm" : [ 10, 15.25 ] }
>
```

Please give an example of what should be expected out of $elemMatch. In which cases is it required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check their documentation on [single-query-condition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/index.html#single-query-condition) :

```
{dim_cm: { $elemMatch :{$gt:1}}}

 /** Is equal to below query cause you only have one condition to match */

{dim_cm: { $gt:1 }}
```

> In which cases is it required?

So considering two of your documents :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04608"), "dim_cm" : [ 14, 21 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460b"), "dim_cm" : [ 22.85, 30 ] }
```

when querying on array field `dim_cm` if you wanted to get documents which have elements `>= 15 & < 20`.

So when you try below code :

```
db.collection.find({ dim_cm: { $gte: 15, $lt: 20 } })

/** Equals to */

db.collection.find({
        "$and" : [ 
            { "dim_cm" : { "$lt" : 20.0 } }, 
            { "dim_cm" : { "$gte" : 15.0 } }
        ]
    })
```

Looking at above `AND` queries, both are same and works great on fields which are just type numbers like `dim_cm : 123 or dim_cm : 12.3` but on arrays queries work differently as such if at-least one element matches with at-least on condition either `$gte` or `$lt` then the entire doc/array will be retrieved. So even if it looks like an `AND` condition but on arrays it works as an `OR` condition retrieving first document in given sample docs as `21 >= 15 & 14 < 20` though `14` is not greater than input `15` and also `21` is not less than input `20` it doesn't matter.

But if you use `$elemMatch` :

```
db.collection.find({ dim_cm: { $elemMatch: { $gte: 15, $lt: 20 } } })
```

You're really applying `AND` operation (`>= 15 & < 20`) on each element in the array i.e; `From [14, 21] : 14 >= 15 && 14 < 20 also 21 >= 15 && 21 < 20`, As no elements in array matches with both conditions then none of the docs will be returned. If any one element matches with conditions then that particular doc will be retrieved.

**Note :**

`$elemMatch` is can be used in query or in [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/), If you used in query we get the documents with entire array where at-least one element in array satisfies input condition but when used as projection operator only the first matching element in array will be returned.